# Laravel many-to-many with 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, many-to-many

I have 3 models: **Movie**, **Celebrity**, **Role**. Each movie has many celebrities and each celebrity has many roles in many movies (for example the movie *"Once Upon a Time"* has celebrity *"Quentin Tarantino"* as roles [*"Director"*,*"Writer"*], and obviously *"Quentin Tarantino"* can have other movies performing different roles.

What is the best way to implement a many-to-many relationship between these 3 models, where we can easily access each movie's staff directly (like `$movie->$roles->director`)

Should we define a pivot table with `movie_id, celebrity_id, role_id` and a primary key of (`movie_id`, `celebrity_id`, `role_id`)?

```php
class Movie extends Model{

    public function movieCelebrityRole()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MovieCelebrityRole::class);
    }

}

class Celebrity extends Model{

    public function movieCelebrityRole()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MovieCelebrityRole::class);
    }

}

class Role extends Model{

    public function userRoleCompany()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MovieCelebrityRole::class);
    }

}


class MovieCelebrityRole extends Model{

    public function movie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Movie::class);
    }

    public function celebrity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Celebrity::class);
    }

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a pivot table with more than two Foreign Keys, or have multiple many-to-many relationships, try to treat it as full model.
This also helps you to define more simple relationships.

Instead of Many-to-Many relationship. You can divide it into multiple of One-to-Many relationships.

E.g: In your case, you're going to have 4 models : Movie, Celebrity, Role, Program.

- Movie hasMany Program.
- Celebrity hasMany Program.
- Role hasMany Program.

---

- Program belongsTo Movie.
- Program belongsTo Celebrity.
- Program belongsTo Role.

For more details, check the Laravel documentation about the One-to-Many relationships :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Actually, I would like to call it MovieCelebrityRole class instead of Program, but your answer is correct. thank you

Comment: Yes, definitely that is a better name and I just want to say an example... Happy to help